# Castle, AOP and Logging in .NET

Tags: .net, logging, castle-windsor, aop

Are there any tutorials or sample programs out there on using AOP, Castle, and logging in a .Net application?  I have found pieces out there but I am looking for something more to help me form a more complete picture.

Thanks,
-Brian

Comment: Try this from Ayende's blog:
[http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Logging--the-AOP-way.aspx](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Logging--the-AOP-way.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

You need to be using a custom Interceptor, which inherits from IInterceptor.  For example:

```
public class LogInterceptor : IInterceptor
{    
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Logger.Write("I'm in your method logging your access");
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps.