# AOP Logging with StructureMap

Tags: logging, castle-windsor, aop, structuremap

I am trying to implement simple logging with AOP approach with StructureMap.

Basically, I want to do what is asked in the question [Castle, AOP and Logging in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238755/castle-aop-and-logging-in-net) with StructureMap.

CastleWindsor has the helpful `IInterceptor` that you can implement and then control when the a method is called with the `IInvocation.Proceed()`. Allowing you to perform logging before and after the call to the method is made.

How can achieve this with StructureMap? I have tired using a custom `Interceptor` but the only handle you get is when the instance is created, not when a method is called on the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would probably work for you:

Create a castle proxy interceptor:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly IMyLogger _logger;
    public LoggingInterceptor(IMyLogger logger) { _logger = logger; }
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        _logger.Log("Before calling " + invocation.Method);
        invocation.Proceed();
        _logger.Log("After calling " + invocation.Method);
    }
}
```

Register this in you SM configuration to wrap all `IFoo` with a proxy:

```
var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
c.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
c.For<IFoo>()
    .EnrichAllWith(instance => 
        proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IFoo>(instance, 
            new LoggingInterceptor(new MyLogger())));
```

All calls to any method on all instances of `IFoo` will now be intercepted by the `LoggingInterceptor`. You can of course filter which calls you want to log by inspecting the instance.

Comment: but if I had to register for all interfaces? how to do this without explicitly specifying for all types?