# Does strucutremap has interception capabitlities, why do i need another libratry like windsor castle for that?

Tags: c#, aop, structuremap, interception

does strucutremap has interception capabitlities, why do i need another library like windsor castle for that?
is there a native way from structuremap to do that?

[AOP Logging with StructureMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745629/aop-logging-with-structuremap) is a similar question but the answer resides back to a castle proxy.

thanks

Comment: All IOC frameworks use the same open source Castle.Proxy2 library. Castle Windsor also depends on Castle.Proxy2, so in a sense Windsor neither has 'native' support.

Comment: yes.. now its castle.core

Comment: So what's the problem? StructureMap didn't built its own interception library, because there already was a great interception library available and reused it. The native way to do this with structure map is by using Castle.Proxy2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.structuremap.net/Interception.htm) answers this:

> StructureMap 2.5+ added the ability to postprocess or even intercept
>   and replace the objects being created.  While **StructureMap will never
>   include its own Aspect Oriented Programming model (the world does not
>   need a new one)**, the interception techniques shown below could be used
>   to apply runtime AOP from existing AOP tools like the Policy Injection
>   Application Block from Microsoft.
>
> In general, interception is specified in three ways:
>
> 1) `OnCreation()` -- Registers an Action to run against the new object after creation
>
> 2) `EnrichWith()` -- Registers a Func that runs against the new object after creation and gives you the option of returning a different object than the original object
>
> 3) A custom class that implements the `TypeInterceptor` interface (the runtime model behind all the interception techniques)

So in short StructureMap's interception capabilities deals with manipulating/replacing configured objects in the container - not applying AOP style interception.

So to summarize:

> does strucutremap has interception capabitlities

Yes, but not for AOP-style interception

> why do i need another library like windsor castle for that?

Because AOP is not in scope for the StructureMap architecture. There are already multiple good solutions (including Castle Proxy).