# Is it possible to use the Unity Policy Injection within StructureMap to provide AOP functionalities?

Tags: unity-container, aop, structuremap, castle-dynamicproxy

I know that we can use Castle Dynamic Proxy within StructureMap to implement the AOP mechanism. A typical example is: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745629/aop-logging-with-structuremap) But can we use Unity Policy Injection within StructureMap instead of Castle Dyanmic Proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered doing your AOP natively with StructureMap? Have a look at the [StructureMap documentation on interception](http://docs.structuremap.net/Interception.htm).